# How to compile .less files from an npm dependency using webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gruntjs, less, webpack

I'm using the npm module [`elemental`](http://elemental-ui.com/), which contains a `/less` folder with all the relevant styling for its react ui. I'm currently trying to do this with [`less-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader):

`/tasks/config/webpack.js`:

```
'use strict';

let path = require('path');
let ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('webpack', {
    client: {
      entry: {
        app: `${process.cwd()}/src/app.jsx`,
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
        path: `${process.cwd()}/dist`,
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|dist)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.less$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!less-loader'),
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
      ],
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack');

};
```

`/src/app.jsx`:

```
'use strict';

let path = require('path');

require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/elemental/less/elemental.less'));
```

But this doesn't seem to work, as it generates a warning:

```
WARNING in ./src/app.jsx
Critical dependencies:
5:0-82 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./src/app.jsx 5:0-82

WARNING in ./src ^\.\/.*$
Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed
 @ ./src ^\.\/.*$
```

I'm interpreting this to mean that you can't use `require()`s that include files from inside `node_modules`.

### Edit

Just to note, there are no `.css` files output anywhere, nor does the output `/dist/app.js` work properly.

Comment: Why not try just write `require('elemental/less/elemental.less');` ?

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko That works!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try just write `require('elemental/less/elemental.less');` ?

In your error message: "5:0-82 the request of a dependency **is an expression**".